# Why does my blender render look smudged?

Tags: rendering, export

[image]

I'm trying to export this scene of a car crash but it looks super smudged like an oil painting. I have like 300 samples here but also tried with 1000 earlier and it didn't look very different. I'm using the denoise from the composite window as some people online said that the regular denoise can cause smudging but it is still happening even after switching. I'm really stumped here if anyone knows how to help.

Comment: This is what it looks like when animated but with fewer samples. It's like the lighting is flickering all around and the scene is all smudged up. https://youtu.be/oDM4x7mRrDE

Comment: Are you sure that the denoising is disabled? Because it looks like it's the denoising effect, also maybe you have a denoise in the Compositor?